# I want to open application automatically when notification is received, is this possible with Firebase and new FCM notifications? Swift3 iOS

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to open application automatically when notification is received, is this possible with Firebase and new FCM notifications?

Comment: You'll have to explain in a little more detail what you want to do, and what problem you are seeing. As it stands, this question is a bit broad, and it is unclear exactly that mechanism you want to use to do what you describe.

Comment: This is not possible. Without user interaction, no application can be opened. Also welcome to SO, please read the [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) help page.

Comment: I want to implement a whatsapp call like feature in my app